# Bash script that counts IDs in square brackets every ten minutes

Tags: bash, sed, grep, uniq

Having this logfile

```
20180917084726:-
20180917085418:[111783178, 111557953, 111646835, 111413356, 111412662, 105618372, 111413557]
20180917115418:[111413432, 111633904, 111783198, 111792767, 111557948, 111413225, 111413281]
20180917105419:[111413432, 111633904, 111783198, 111792767, 111557948, 111413225, 111413281]
20180917085522:[111344871, 111394583, 111295547, 111379566, 111352520]
20180917090022:[111344871, 111394583, 111295547, 111379566, 111352520]
```

The format of the input log is:

timestamp is in  format YYYYMMDDhhmmss

I would like to know how to write a script that outputs one line for each ten minute slice of the day the count of unique IDs that were returned

The result is as this one:

```
20180917084:0
20180917085:12
20180917115:7
20180917105:7
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please correct your expected output as per shown input itself and let us know then, it doesn't look good as per shown input.

Comment: Hi RavinderSingh13, it's corrected now

Comment: What's the purpose of that log format? It's nonstandard, harder to parse than it needs to be, and less readable than it could be.

Comment: The log was generated by a program that collects IDs per request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

awk: Uses colon or comma as the field separator.

```
awk -F '[,:]' '
    {
        key = substr($1,1,11)"0"
        count[key] += ($2 == "-" ? 0 : NF-1)
    } 
    END {
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"
        for (key in count) print key, count[key]
    }
' file
```

```
201809170840 0
201809170850 12
201809170900 5
201809171050 7
201809171150 7
```

---

To filter on today's date, you could say:

```
gawk -F '[,:]' '
    BEGIN {today = strftimme("%Y%m%d", systime())}
    $0 ~ "^"today { key = ...
```

or

```
awk -F '[,:]' -v "today=$(date "+%Y%m%d")" '
    $0 ~ "^"today { key = ...
```

or pipe the existing awk code to `| grep "^$(date +%Y%m%d)"`

Comment: It looks very good, what if I want to print only info for today? 20180917 (based on date) and no other days?

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, it will be give you output in same order in which timestamp occurrence is happening in Input_file.

```
awk '
{
  val=substr($0,1,11)
}
!a[val]++{
  b[++count]=val
}
match($0,/\[.*\]/){
  num=split(substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH),array,",")
  c[val]+=num
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
    print b[i],c[b[i]]+0
  }
}'   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
20180917084 0
20180917085 12
20180917115 7
20180917105 7
20180917090 5
```

***EDIT:*** Adding a solution in case your any of the field is having NULL value so putting a check in above code too now.

```
awk '
{
  val=substr($0,1,11)
}
!a[val]++{
  b[++count]=val
}
match($0,/\[.*\]/){
  count1=""
  num=split(substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH),array,",")
  for(j=1;j<=num;j++){
    if(array[j]){
      count1++
    }
  }
  c[val]+=count1
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
    print b[i],c[b[i]]+0
  }
}'  Input_file
```

Comment: Good answer as well, Can you have the chance to easily validate only for today's date?

Answer (score 1):

your input and output are not consistent but I guess you want something like this

```
 $ awk -F: '{k=sprintf("%10d",$1/1000); n=gsub(",",",",$2); a[k]+=(n?n+1:n)} 
        END {for(k in a) print k":"a[k] | "sort" }' file 

20180917084:0
20180917085:12
20180917090:5
20180917105:7
20180917115:7
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -ne '
    ($timestamp, @ids) = /([0-9]+)/g;
    substr $timestamp, -3, 3, "";
    @{ $seen{$timestamp} }{@ids} = ();
    END {
        for my $timestamp (sort keys %seen) {
            print "$timestamp:", scalar keys %{ $seen{$timestamp} }, "\n";
        }
    }' < file.log
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line
- [substr](http://p3rl.org/substr) here replaces the last three characters of the timestamp with an empty string
- `%seen` is a hash of hashes, for each timestamp the inner hash records what ids were seen
- [keys](http://p3rl.org/keys) in scalar context return the count of the keys, in this case the number of unique ids per timestamp.

Comment: I'm curious why you didn't use a hash of arrays: `push @{$seen{$timestamp}}, @ids;`, then `print $timestamp, ":", scalar @{$seen{$timestamp}}, "\n";`